# Photon hits an electron perpendicular to its velocity, Relativity and Work?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, electrons, conservation-laws, work

In the phenomenon of the Compton scattering a photon can hit a free electron under any angle.
The photon can be regarded as a 'complex' of two photons one along the velocity v of the electron and another perpendicular to v.
Let not be interested in the ‘first’ photon (along v).
So there is a photon carrying energy E and hitting perpendicularly to v a free electron.
I wonder:

1. Can the photon change the energy of the electron? E.g. does a law prohibit inelastic scattering in this case? As I think there are only the Energy conservation law and Impulse conservation law acting here and I can’t see how they prohibit this. In fact as far as I remember there was red shift in Compton (right?)
2. If it can not - then how about Relativity because a stationary electron will surely change its Energy and velocity when hit by a photon?
3. If it can - how about the statement that a force (the photon) does not do work on perpendicular moving body (the electron)?

Comment: I checked and there is a red shift. The photon is captured by the electron and then it radiates another photon of lower energy, which means that the energy of the photon increases (according to impulse conservation it can not has the initial impulse hence velocity direction). That means that the electron (in case of photon of perpendicular impulse) obtains additional velocity perpendicular to the initial one. But this is against the notion in classical mechanics that a perpendicular force doesn't do work?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Feynman diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Compton_Scattering_Feynman_Diagram.png) for [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).

[image: comptscat]

Using it one can calculate the crossection of photon electron scattering.  One has to realize that both electrons and photons are quantum mechanical entities, and their interaction cannot be deterministic event per event, the way you imagine. The only predictions are distributions of many interactions that can be compared to the result of computing the diagram above. i.e. $Ψ^*Ψ$ , where $Ψ$  is the wavefunction of the specific system that is interacting.

The mathematics is such that special relativity holds and energy and momentum , angular momentum and quantum number conservation where relevant, event per event. Just it is not possible to set up  deterministic conditions event per event. Only distributions can be compared with experiments.

Your 1.2.3. are in the framework of classical physics, and quantum mechanics had to be invented *because* classical physics does not work in the microworld

Comment: Thanks for considerations. Do you imply that their doesn't exist a scattering process like the Feynman diagram of first order? What is Compton scattering then? In the end QM must also explain classical physics phenomena! Also there are now experiments with single electrons and photons (on demand!).

Comment: The theory does not model single events, the predictions of the theory are for ensembles of events with the same boundary conditions/ QM_solutions . By contrast  in classical one event scatterings one has a solution for the scattered products. There are complicated mathematical ways of showing how classical fields  are built up from quantum ones ( and then classical physics can be applied) https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html  , but not in the micro dimensions of electrons and photons, that has to be QM

Comment: Do you think that 1.2.3 and in the end the fact that perpendicular force does not do work can not be explained by classical physics?

Comment: @Mercury  Not on an event basis, at the quantum mechanical level only consercation laws for quantum numbers, energy momentum, angular momentum hold. tracking cannot be predicted at the event level,

Comment: When a perpendicular force is applied only the direction of velocity changes independent what the magnitude of the force is or the velocity (e.g. electron [e-] in magnetic field). If the process can be described by Compton scattering amplitudes there is always a red shift for the photon and these means that e- gains energy hence velocity increase.

Comment: Here important is only energy momentum conservation which as you say hold. (of course Compton is with X rays but I cant see what other mechanism different from Feynman diagrams for Compton scattering QM offers for a force). In my opinion neither CP no QM offers an explanation for the case. Of course CP should be fixed but QM should be perfect. The problem is I cant see how QM accounts for it. (by the way Compton scattering is also a perpendicular force applied in 0 time).

Comment: Beneath stuffu is stating that first photons dont experience red shift (e.g they are obligated to elastic scattering). Is there elastic scattering or only Compton?

Comment: @Mercury I meant first photons experience very very very small redshift, and last photons experiences much larger redshift. Think about laser beam hitting something that starts moving.

Comment: @stuffu Where do you know this from? I always thought there can only be Compton scattering what else?

Comment: @Mercury I know that Doppler shift, when light bounces off of a thing, depends on velocity of the thing. And I know that velocity of a thing is changing when the thing is being hit by light. Therefore I know that there is a changing Doppler shift of light when said light is hitting said thing. If the thing is so massive that light has no effect on it, then there is no changing Doppler shift.

Answer (score 0):

1: First the photon expends no energy as it pushes the electron that is not moving in the direction of the push.

2: Then the photon expends some energy as it pushes the electron that is now moving in the direction of the push.

Now maybe 1 and 2 happen in zero time, simultaneously, or whatever. I mean, if my description is too simple, the reader may add some fancy stuff according to his taste.

Anyway, the definition of Compton-scattering is that the thing that the photon scatters from, like electron, is a low-mass object that the photon can set in motion.

While the definition of Thomson-scattering is that the thing that the photon scatters from, like electron, is a high-mass object that the photon can not set in motion.

Comment: 1. is impossible ; if 1 and 2 are simultaneous one has the case I describe.

Comment: @Mercury  Ok, but: Laser pulse hits something. Photons at the front of the pulse do not experience Doppler shift, photons at the rear of the pulse experience Doppler shift. On the average the pulse experience some energy change. A 1 MeV photon experiences the same energy change that a 1MeV pulse of light experiences, when scattering off of some object.

Comment: I dont know about these. But for Compton there is red shift for each photon. Look at the answer of Anna.

Comment: I very curious where is this statement about the laser pulse. I would appreciate your citation.